# How can I make internal anchor links work with WordPress's permalinks?

Tags: permalinks, redirect

I've got a custom template page called `'shop'`, which is found at the URL `http://mysite.com/shop/`. This page lays out all the posts of post_type `'product'` like this:

```
<div class="product">  
<a name="product-name"></a>
<img src="path/to/image.jpg" />  
<h4>Product name</h4>`  
<p>A description of the product.</p>  
</div>`
```

On another page, I've got a link like this:

```
<a href="/shop#product-name">Buy this product!</a>
```

I want that link to go to the `/shop` page, then scroll down to position the page right at the anchor link for this product. But it seems like WordPress' *'pretty permalinks'* redirection is getting in the way: as soon as it switches to the `/shop#product-name` page, the URL gets rewritten to `/shop/` and the browser leaves the page scrolled at the top.

My `.htaccess` file is exactly what WordPress generated: it looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any help in getting these anchor links to work properly would be much appreciated.

*(**Moderator Note:** Title was originally "My permalinks setup doesn't like anchor links to another page.")*

Comment: Was title change really necessary here? Question is really about anchor link, not messing with permalink setup (which might or might not be required in the end).

Comment: I agree—in the end, the solution involved changing the anchor links, not the permalinks. (Of course, my original title was no masterpiece.) I've changed it again, to something that I hope works better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dumb question, but had you tried:

```
<a href="/shop/#product-name">Buy this product!</a>
```

Comment: I think this is the exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hi **@Gabriel Roth**:

Any chance you can just code it like this? *(note the trailing slash after `/shop`)*:

```
<a href="/shop/#product-name">Buy this product!</a>
```

Of course if you must have it without a trailing slash I think this will do what you need although I can't fully test for your use-case, you'll have to try it. You copy this code into a plugin or more easily, your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter('user_trailingslashit', 'no_trailing_slash_on_shop');
function no_trailing_slash_on_shop($url_path) {
  if ($url_path=='/shop/')
    $url_path = '/shop';
  return $url_path;
}
```